# Daylight Saving Time Changes in Trigger (Data Factory v2)

Tags: azure-data-factory

How can I set a Trigger in a pipeline (Data Factory v2) to scheduler a specific start hour to a Country with Daylight Saving Time Changes?

Comment: Could you clarify the request? Are you worried that if you schedule a trigger for (say) 1:30am that it will be skipped one day per year and execute twice one day per year? Do you *need* to schedule the trigger for a local time that is skipped/ambiguous on DST transitions?

Comment: For example, in countries that used Western European Summer Time, the hour will change for 6 months +1 hour comparing to the UTC hour. The idea will be having the same hour all the year for the same region, as is posible to define in monitor of DFv2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve found a simple work around is to start your pipeline with the following if condition.

```
if(Equals(addHours(convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'Central Standard Time'), 5, 'HH'),utcNow('HH')),true,false)
```

Lets break the if down into the following lines…

```
1. if(
2. Equals(
3. addHours(convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'Central Standard Time'), 5, 'HH')
4. ,utcNow('HH')
5. )
6. ,true,false)
```

In line 3 we get current time in UTC (19:30) and convert to CST (15:30), add 5 hours, and then take just the hours value
19:30 >> 15:30 + 5:00 = 19

In line 4 we are getting the timestamp in UTC and extracting just the hours (HH) and in this case it is 19.

Finally this is wrapped in an “Equals” statement… if the two hours values are equal then true, else false.

If true, we do nothing and continue on to the next step of the pipeline.  If false then we are no longer in day light savings time and we wait one hour to continue.  I have found this works even when the difference between UTC and CST spans midnight.

Below is the json….

```json
{
  "name": "If DST",
  "type": "IfCondition",
  "dependsOn": [],
  "userProperties": [],
  "typeProperties": {
    "expression": {
      "value": "@if(Equals(addHours(convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'Central Standard Time'), 5, 'HH'),utcNow('HH')),true,false)",
      "type": "Expression"
    },
    "ifFalseActivities": [
      {
        "name": "Wait 1 hour",
        "type": "Wait",
        "dependsOn": [],
        "userProperties": [],
        "typeProperties": {
          "waitTimeInSeconds": 3600
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: so I assume ADF calculates the daylight saving for CST? if so why not just use CST to set the times in the first place?

Comment: shouldn't we be using this to wait one hour if we are within a certain date (start of Daylight saving and its end) ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers), even though there's a time zone property for the trigger, only UTC is currently supported. When other time zones are supported, specifying that time zone would make the trigger fire at that local time.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this, and it's a bit hacky, but as a workaround, could you not change to a hourly scheduled trigger and then pass in the UTC triggered time to the pipeline. You could then have another trigger param which is the timezone and actual time that when you want to exectute.

The first step on the pipeline would hit an Azure function and convert the time to your local time zone (which would consider daylight saving). An IF statement would then exit or continue if the resulting time matched the requested timezone hour.

In the interests of time/cost/tech debt I probably would not do though - I would just manually work out the different and update it when daylight saving happened.